# Duplicate numbers in list with list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to duplicate all numbers in a list of alpha values as cleanly as possible but can't figure out how.

```
alphas = [.001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100]

data_alphas = [a for num in alphas for i in range(2)]
```

This should return

```
[.001, .001, .01, .01, .1, .1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 100, 100]
```

Comment: could you explain why you want to do this, so I can assist with some code? I need to understand your usage first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest and easiest way is to just duplicate the list and sort it.

```py
alphas = [.001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100]
data_alphas = sorted(alphas * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels kinda "hacky" and is probably not the most pythonic way to solve this but it should work.

```
alphas = [.001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100]

data_alphas = [alphas[int(i/2)] for i in range(len(alphas)*2)]
```

It outputs

```
[0.001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 100, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
list(sum(zip(v, v), ()))
```

sorry for one-liner, there might be better options though